# What are the uses of wordpress widget? and how to create a new widget?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I want to know how to create a custom WordPress widget and what are the uses of widget>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A widget in wordpress can be used in a sidebar.

The wordpress codex provides you all the information you need to create a widget.

The only thing that is missing is where to put your code: you can create a custom plugin or paste it directly in your functions.php file in your template.

That's the link to the codex if you don't want to google it!

[Wordpress Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)